# What does "Liti" and "Obrig" mean in the 20th episode of the podcast eat.READ.sleep?

Tags: listening-comprehension

I have been listening to the German literature podcast eat.READ.sleep, and in the quiz portion in 20th episode ["Feuerzangenbowle mit Katharina, Jan und Daniel"](https://www.ndr.de/nachrichten/info/20-Feuerzangenbowle-mit-Katharina-Jan-und-Daniel,audio803836.html) at 47:23 Katharina introduces her question with

> **Liti**-Klick ist die **Obrig**, also mit mehreren Hinweisen zum Erfolg.

What did Katharina mean by **Liti** and **Obrig**? I have been unable to find anything relevant for "Liti" and "Obrig" is only part of "Obrigkeit", so I'm wondering if I heard those words wrong.

What did Katharina actually say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She said **Rubrik**, not **Obrig**.

Liti-Klick seems to be some game mode description for the 'Quiz' they do on this podcast. I personally never heard that before.

Comment: Thanks, Rubrik makes a lot more sense. If Liti-Klick is a unique description for their podcast, Liti is probably short for Literatur.

Comment: And -Klick is probably a reference to Dalli-Klick, a game in a TV show in the 70s and 80s (Dalli Dalli) where a picture was unveiled gradually, similar to the literature hints in the podcast.